# Cannot login with Linux Mint 19 via terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, login

I cannot login via terminal (I do not know if this is because of Mint or Ubuntu).
When I enter the username, I want to enter the password, but what it does, it autoenters with an enter it goes like this:

```
Terminal hostname tty1

hostname login: root
Password: 
_ <- then it goes right away here
```

No way to enter with a password. Via GUI it works, but sometimes I need to be able to use the terminal tty.

Comment: i cannot show as i cannot login via terminal , bummer :(

Comment: Perhaps this (known kernel bug)? [TTY doesn't wait for password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113704/tty-doesnt-wait-for-password)

Comment: yes, it is true, it last one works with Linux Mint 4.15.0-43 is working, reference as well: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113704/tty-doesnt-wait-for-password